# PHP While loop do so many times in db

Tags: php, database, while-loop

I'm trying to detect if the data in the db is expired or not, and it works prefectly fine as long as I only have on data to check when there are mutiple data needed to be check then everything will somehow follow the first one's behavior

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe))
{   
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Taipei");
    echo $row['ExpeTime']." ";
    echo $ExpTim=strtotime($row['ExpeTime']);
    echo " ";
    echo $TWnowSec=date("U");
    echo " ";

    /*if($ExpTim>$TWnowSec){
        echo "沒過期";
    }elseif($ExpTim<$TWnowSec){
        echo "過期了";
    }*/

    if($ExpTim<$TWnowSec) {
        $sql= "UPDATE productneeds SET Status='已過期';";
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            echo "update failed";
        }else{
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            echo "sucess";
        }
    }else {
        echo "{$row['O_no']} is not expired<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your SQL statement "UPDATE productneeds SET Status='已過期';" does not have a WHERE part and does therefor update ALL rows in the productneeds, not only one row which might be what you expect?

Comment: Your prepared/execute handling is not quite correct. See [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) where you assign `$stmt` to prepare call whose first argument should be connection object, `$conn`. Then you execute the query using `$stmt`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a pure SQL update query and avoid any PHP looping. Since you appear to be looping from a different recordset fetch, run MySQL's supported `UPDATE...JOIN` query to update records across one or more tables. Some adjustments required to achieve your needed time zone. Below is a demonstration for you to finalize:

```
// SET MYSQL SESSION TIME ZONE TO GMT
$sql = "SET TIME_ZONE = '+00:00';"        
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// RUN UPDATE + JOIN WITH ADJUSTMENT FOR 'Asia/Taipei' TIME ZONE
$sql = "UPDATE productneeds p
        INNER JOIN myotherTable t
           ON p.myRelatedID = t.myRelatedID
        SET p.Status = '已過期' 
        WHERE t.ExpeTime < NOW() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR"; 

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```